# How to copy an excel file using microsoft graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to copy an excel file in the same folder in my sharepoint account using following API - `POST /drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/copy` but it gives message 'Operation not supported'.So how to do this?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your issue. I have a folder in my drive and it has an excel file. I am trying to copy that file into same folder by using the below call. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drives/{driveid}/Items/{file id which you want to copy}/copy`.
Request Body: `{
  "parentReference": {
    "driveId": "{Same driveid of above call}",
    "id": "{Folderid}"
  },
  "name": "contosoplan(copy).xlsx"
}` Give a try with this. it worked for me.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity Thanks for your reply i tried this but still i am getting this message **Operation not supported**. I am using communication site and i don't know what went wrong even i have also given the required permission according to documentation.

Comment: Can you please share the Request body and also the requestid and timestamp for the failed request.

Comment: I found that it was a issue in my header section and after resolving it, now its works fine with both the above APIs so thanks for replying.

Comment: Can you please tell us which header change helped you move forward?

Comment: I was checking on postman and the header contain **Prefer - apiversion=2.1**, although it does not create any issue in other APIs but in copy it create issues so when i removed this, it started working fine.

Comment: Interesting one. Moving this to answer as it can help others find their answers to their questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments you can try the below scenario.

I have a folder in my drive and it has an excel file. I am trying to copy that file into same folder by using the below call.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drives/{driveid}/Items/{file id which you want to copy}/copy`

```
Request Body: 
{   
    "parentReference": {     
                            "driveId": "{Same driveid of above call}",     
                            "id": "{Folderid}"   
                       },   
    "name": "contosoplan(copy).xlsx" 
}
```

Give a try with this. And as you said the apiversion=2.1 should not me used in some scenarios according to this [Github Thread](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues/369#issuecomment-632883767) as it doesn't have feature parity with default version.